# delete hyphen from an input field in angular 2 + reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms, angular-validation

So, i just want remove when we delete data from input fields
when we try to clear the input field then it's not going to clear because of i have added hyphen dynamically
so is there a way to delete the or clear the input fields.

Basically i have added hyphen in the input field, but i am not able to delete hyphen when i trye to clear or deleting the data. please somebody help me out.

[Here is my running code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-date-format-limit-customized-v3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905432/automatic-hyphens-while-typing-date-in-input-type-date-angular-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already half way done all you need to:

**Replace**

```
if(event.keyCode === 8 || event.key === "Delete") return;
```

**With**

```
if(!event.data) return;
```

Comment: Yes i tried out but it's kind of stuck after removing hyphen. i didn't get it how can i delete or clear the input filed.

Comment: @mp3 why it stuck I have tried your example and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, now it's working fine thank you so much. :-) i did spelling mistake

Comment: @mp3 perfect, you can accept and upvote the answer it will help other colleagues.

Comment: one more thing it's just user experience when user enter invalid **Day** like 45 then user should not able to type anything until he enter right day

Comment: Its bcz the logic you added behaves like this, you could refactor `if` condition part in your `addHyphen` method.

Comment: And i forget to mentioned that mine angular project works on mobile webview and mobile webview doesn't support **(keydown)** so is there a way deal with **(input)** only .
so if you want to reproduce the error you can open above code preview in mobile.

Comment: @mp3 I have updated my answer now you can use `input` with slight change in your `if` condition, try it out.

Comment: wow, nice thank you so much. i am really appreciate brother. thanks a lot.

Comment: @mp3 glad to help you :)